# How to getElementsById from an input with multiple classes

Tags: javascript

I have an input field:

```
    <input name="det[1][desc]" id="desc_1" type="text" value="" class="desc" style="width:200px"/>
```

working great, with my script:

```
        var descGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('desc');
        for ( var r=0; r < descGroup.length; r++){
            var newNumr = r+1; 
                        ...blah blah blah
```

but when I add **A SECOND CLASS (blue)** to the input field:

```
    <input name="det[1][desc]" id="desc_1" type="text" value="" class="desc, blue" style="width:200px"/>
```

My script won't work and it says descGroup.length is 0, when there should be, and was 7!

Is getElementsByClassName only good if your input has **one** class, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: comma not needed after desc in class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as much classes as you want (remember about [256](http://css-tricks.com/classes-beats-an-id/) classes though) however you should use a space as a separator not a comma:

```
<input class="desc blue" name="det[1][desc]" id="desc_1" type="text" value="" style="width:200px"/>
```

Similarly if you want to use a class names combination in `` `getElementsByClassName ``:

```
var descGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('desc blue');
```

Comment: Fantastic. Worked perfectly.